# Logging request length using IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttpmodule

I've made an IHttpModule that logs web requests. It logs POST requests just fine. However for GET requests, the length always seems to be zero. Is there a way to get the length of the GET request?

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += ContextBeginRequest;
    }

    private void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string url = app.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
            string requestType = app.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType;
            long requestLength = app.Request.InputStream.Length;
            Log(url, requestType, requestLength);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET` request usually don't have a message body and, thus, the `Content-Length` will be zero.

Comment: Thanks Rodrick, but how do I get the length of the entire request? (all the HTTP header stuff)

Comment: @Fidel I can't test this now, but you could try iterating over the server variables directly. I'd start with ALL_RAW.

Comment: Thanks Rodrick, yep ServerVariables["ALL_RAW"] gets pretty damn close. However it doesn't contain the first line of the HTTP request.

Comment: @Fidel: First line is simply `GET <AbsolutePathAndQuery> HTTP/1.1` (the verb can be get from Request.HttpMethod and the path/query from Request.Url.PathAndQuery)